# How do I redirect users after submit button click on my landing page?

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code and I am not sure what type of header should I use for redirect an user after he hit submit button.

I tryed several solutions , nothing worked until now!

With this code I was not able to to anything:

```
function redirect() {
  window.location.replace("login.php");
  return false;
}
```

Would appreciate any advice! This is the original code I have on the mail.php

```
<?php
define('admin_email','contact@....'); // Change admin email here for example admin@yoursite.com
define('website_name','site-name'); // Change website name here for example yoursite.com
define('website_url', 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('EMAIL_FROM', 'noreply@'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

function strict_secure($str){
    $str = strip_tags(trim($str));
    return $str;
}
function sendEmail($to,$from,$subject,$message,$headname){
    $headers="MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers.="Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers.="From: ".$headname.'<'.$from.'>';
    return mail ($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}


if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='submitform')
{
    $N = array();
    $N = $_POST['formInput'];   
    $path =  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    $admin_message = '<p>Dear Admin, Form submitted on '.website_url.'<br>Detail is as following.</p>';
    foreach( $N as $label => $value ){
        $admin_message .= '<p>'.ucwords($label).' : '.$value.'</p>';    
    }
    $admin_message .= '<p>Form submitted on URL:<a href="'.$path.'">'.$path.'</a></p>';
    $admin_message .= '<br><br>';
    $admin_message .= 'Regards,<br />
    '.website_name.'<br />
    '.website_url.'
    ';


    $user_message = 'Dear '.strict_secure($N['name']).',<br>';
    $user_message .= 'Thank you very much for submitting information. We will contact you shortly.';
    $user_message .= 'Regards,<br />
    '.website_name.'<br />
    '.website_url.'
    ';

    $admin_subject = 'Form Received From '.website_name;
    $user_subject = 'Thank you - '.website_name;

    $sendToAdmin = $sendToUsers = '';

    $sendToAdmin = sendEmail(admin_email,EMAIL_FROM,$admin_subject,$admin_message,website_name);
    if( isset( $N['email'] ) && ! empty( $N['email'] ) ){
        $sendToUsers = sendEmail(strict_secure($N['email']),EMAIL_FROM,$user_subject,$user_message,website_name);
    }


    if($sendToAdmin || $sendToUsers)
    {
        $message ='Success::<div class="alert alert-success"><strong><i class="fa fa-info message-icon"></i>Message Sent Successfully.</strong></div>';     
    }else{
        $message ='Error::<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong><i class="fa fa-info message-icon"></i>Something Went Wrong While Sending Message.</strong></div>';
    }
    echo $message;
}
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Use window.location.href("login.php");

Comment: "Use window.location.href("login.php");"  - Will this line be added in the headers ?

Comment: No in your redirect function.

Comment: It doesn't work, nothing changes/happenes

Comment: At the end of the php code add this header("Location:login.php");

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
header("Location: login.php");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Thanks for your comment , "header("Location: login.php");" still does not work....

Comment: @koko2020 you need to send the headers before any visual output, so you should add the header code at the top of your php file

Comment: Like this:   <?php
header("Location: login.php");
define('admin_email','contact@....'); // Change admin email here for example admin@yoursite.com
define('website_name','site-name'); // Change website name here for example yoursite.com
define('website_url', 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('EMAIL_FROM', 'noreply@'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);